# Pandas - Apply() using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to create a new column "even" and trying to put even numbers into them

```
df["even"] = df.apply(list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, list(range(21)))),axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

I am getting a lot of error messages.

Comment: You could use a simple list comprehension `df["even"] = [i for i in range(21) if i%2==0]`.

Comment: what is range 21 come from , what is your shape of df

Comment: Usually it helps if you read error messages you get, or if you can't figure out what they say, at least add them to the question so others can read them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your df is structured, but the general solution will look like this.

```
def even_rule(x):
    return x if x%2 == 0 else 0

df = df.apply(even_rule, axis=1)
```

You should be able to modify this based on the structure of your df.

Comment: ```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv", engine="python", skipfooter=3)

df["even"] = df.apply(list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, list(range(21)))),axis=1)
print(df.head())
```